# Is top === self is always true in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was debugging a javascript application i came across this snippet of code.

```
if (self === top) {
   // do some work
}
```

I have seen `this` and `self` many times and i never even know `top` exists.
Here `self === top` outputs **true** then why we have identical objects.
**Update:**

1. My question is `top` always refer to window as `self`
2. In web worker we don't have access to `window` object directly so we use `self`, can we use `top` there?

Comment: need more code,and guess `self` maybe `this` maybe `window` or iframe `window` and  `top` maybe always the top `window`.So,maybe `if (self === top)` just want to be sure if it is in the top `window` not in a iframe

Comment: `self` is also `window` ... and `top` is the "topmost" ... i.e. if your page is in an iframe, `top` is **not** `self`

Comment: i dont know `top`, that's why i asked why two of them in DOM api.

Comment: @Srinivas Without the code related to `self` we are just guessing what it does. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I updated question

Answer (score 3):

In the `Window` object, top references the topmost window. While self references the current window.

When this does make sense? Example you have a page on an iframe like this `<iframe src="page.html"></iframe>`.

When you reference your script in that iframe.

```
if (self === top) {
   // do some work
}
```

Your code snippet above will not evaluate to true. Because self will have the iframe `Window` object and top references to the topmost browser `Window` object.